# Update pandas DataFrame based on index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])

     x    y
A  NaN  NaN
B  NaN  NaN
C  NaN  NaN
```

I need to update column 'x' based on matching the index value to the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'A': "map_1", 'B': "map_2", "c": "map_3"}
```

So, the end result should be;

```
     x     y
A  map_1  NaN
B  map_2  NaN
C  map_3  NaN
```

I know how to use the `map` function if I was comparing another column, but I need to compare the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['x'] = df.index.map(my_dict)
```

Output:  *Note the typo on my_dict small c instead of C.*

```
       x    y
A  map_1  NaN
B  map_2  NaN
C    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: yes, that's it, thanks. I didn't even thing of index.map